# async.apply inside async.waterfall

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-async

I have the following snippet of code

```
async.waterfall([
  // Read directory
  async.apply(fs.readdir, '../testdata'),
  // Load data from each file
  function(files, callback) {
    async.each(files, loadDataFromFile, callback);
  }
], function(err) {
  if (err) {
    api.logger.error('Error while inserting test data', err);
  }
  next();
});
```

Is there a way I could replace this piece:

```
function(files, callback) {
  async.each(files, loadDataFromFile, callback);
}
```

with just a function? Like I did above, using `async.apply()` I replaced this:

```
function(callback) {
  fs.readdir('../testdata', callback);
}
```

I know I could create my own helper function to do this, or I can leave it like this, but I was wondering if there's a way to do this using only functions like `.bind()` or `.apply()`.

I've thought about using `.bind()` then `.apply()` but this would result in `function(loadDataFromFile, files, callback)` which is not okay.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I was wondering if there's a way to do this using only functions like .bind() or .apply().

Not using only native functions, or only those from `async` it seems. As you have noticed, one would need to `flip` the `each` function. Some implementations of partial application (like Underscore) allow intermediate arguments, but you would need to explicitly include them.

An example with [lodash's `partialRight`](http://lodash.com/docs#partialRight):

```
async.waterfall([
  _.partial(fs.readdir, '../testdata'), // Read directory
  _.partialRight(async.each, loadDataFromFile), // Load data from each file
], function(err) {
  if (err)
    api.logger.error('Error while inserting test data', err);
  next();
});
```

Possible you will need to `bind` the method to the correct context though, like `fs.readdir.bind(fs, '../testdata')`.

Comment: Nice, thank you! Underscore's `.partial` looks like what I need, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Yes, yet you would need `_.partial(async.each, _, loadDataFromFile)` - I prefer `partialRight` :-)